# Can't insert the fontawesome icon where the white square is

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a div with a `li`, each `li` has a square icon (that was a bad perform of awesome icon before). Now I tried to insert the correct fontawesome icon (`<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>`, for example). I want to replace the square icon that has now, with the correct fontawesome icon (the fontawesome icon library with `<i>` code that I just mentioned work's for me, the problem is I can't get to replace the square icon with the correct `html` version of fontawesome (`<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>`). You can see a live example here of my problem [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html).

[image]

The square icon's get a 3d cube effect flip on top when I `mousehover` it, but if I insert the fontawesome icons like the HTML provided below, it's shows like that and no 3d cube `mousehover` flip effect css `transform`:

[image]

```css
.social-head-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000000000000000;
  float: right;
  width: 138px;
  font-size: 0px;
  background: #c23f69;
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  right: 48px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  top: 75px;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.container-social ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: perspective(1px);
  margin: 0;
  height: 51px;
  background: #c23f69;
  width: 197px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.container-social ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 51px;
  width: 51px;
}

.container-social ul li a {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #333;
}

.container-social li a span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-social ul li a span:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #c23f69;
  color: #fff;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-social ul li:hover a span:before {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container-social ul li a span:after {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(50%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container-social ul li.facebook a span:after {
  background: #3c579e;
}

.container-social ul li.twitter a span:after {
  background: #1da1f3;
}

.container-social ul li.instagram a span:after {
  background: #f09433;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f09433', endColorstr='#bc1888', GradientType=1);
}

.container-social ul li:nth-child(4) a span:after {
  background: #0077B5;
}

.container-social ul li:nth-child(5) a span:after {
  background: #3cba54;
}

.container-social ul li:hover a span:after {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container-social ul li.facebook a span:before,
.container-social ul li.facebook a span:after {
  content: '\f09a';
}

.container-social ul li.instagram a span:before,
.container-social ul li.instagram a span:after {
  content: '\f16d';
}

.container-social ul li.twitter a span:before,
.container-social ul li.twitter a span:after {
  content: '\f099';
}
```

```html
<div class="float-right social-head-container">
  <div class="container-social">
    <ul>
      <div class="social-head">
        <li class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="social-head">
        <li class="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="social-head">
        <li class="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the example?

Comment: See it in: https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab (Top right zone). You have the link in the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were referencing to the wrong font family.

With:

```css
.container-social ul li a span:before,
.container-social ul li a span:after {
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
}
```

it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is correct but whatever your using Unicode in css that is wrong that's why it's not working properly.

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> unicode is f39e

<i class="fab fa-twitter"> unicode is f099

<i class="fab fa-instagram"> unicode is f16d
```